# Migrate mysql from 2.2.9 CE to 2.3.3 EE

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

It it possible to just take a mysql dump from Magento 2.2.9 community edition and import it into Magento enterprise cloud 2.3.3 and what are tools to use to do the job. Specifically to do the importing into enterprise cloud?

Comment: no way. different versions

Comment: why do you need to use cloud? just upgrade magento community to latest version and configure your own infrastructure on AWS or DigitalOcean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to import your mysql dump from Magento 2.2.9 directly to Magento enterprise cloud, it isn't impossible! To resolve it:

Firstly, you need to export it as Database format.

Next, use an automated data migration tool to transfer your database to Magento cloud.

You can consult Magento document here for more information: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003254334-Create-database-dump-on-Cloud